# VoIP call like whatsapp/ skype

Tags: android, ios, voip, communication, phone-call

We are making an app which works like whatsapp.
Our server should be able to send calls (robot call) and text messages (SMS) to other (internal verified) phones.
How is this possible (voip? sip?) and what would it cost (approximately 10k users)?

I really appreciate any reply!

Comment: yes it possible by sip

Comment: You can use iOS pushkit for iOS users https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: you can use Twilio